# Azure Devops Pipelines Powershell SQL Command

Tags: debugging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I got a problem. I try to insert a value in my sql database while using a pipline in Azure DevOps.
The following task should do the job:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
displayName: 'Run PowerShell Script'
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
$SQLServer = "SQLServer"
$SQLDBName = "TestData"
$uid ="xxxx"
$pwd = "yyyy"
$SqlInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Test (Testcolumn) VALUES ('Test');"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlInsertQuery
$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlConnection.Close()"
```

Executing the script in Powershell on my machine is no problem. But if I try to execute it in a Pipeline it throws an error:

```
Connecting to SQL Server: xxxx, Database: TestData, Username: xxxx

Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

- Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

At D:\a\_temp\746eb8f6-45de-4a40-943e-f70f1bf097d7.ps1:14 char:1

+ $SqlConnection.Open()

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

The agent is hosted on the same machine as the sql server. The remote connection is allowed in SSMS.
I tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.
Also I'm pretty new to Azure DevOps and don't have a lot of knowledge.

I would be glad if someone could help me. Thanks!

What I already tried:

- login with sa credentials
- using the RUN SQLCMD Script from the Marketplace.
- adding the port number to the connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check the agent used in your pipeline yaml.

As per the path `D:\a\_temp` of error in your message:

```
At D:\a\_temp\746eb8f6-45de-4a40-943e-f70f1bf097d7.ps1:14 char:1
```

It appears you are using Microsoft-Hosted Windows agent actually. On `self-hosted` agent, the path should be like below(agent folder\work_temp...):

[image]

If you use self-hosted agent, should use format below:

```
trigger: none

pool: 
  name: SelfHostedAgentPoolName
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your complete yaml? Is it Azure DevOps Server or Azure DevOps Service?

*The agent is hosted on the same machine as the sql server.*

Could you check this script manually on this server?

Additionally, check your `pool` section. In case Azure DevOps Service, yaml without `pool` section will performed on Azure Hosted build agents that do not have access to your SQL server.